# Как правильно говорить о тайской валюте: 100 бат или батов?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение

Живу в Таиланде. Все привыкли говорить «100 бат», а многие сайты типа «Грамоты» или sklonenie-slova.ru говорят, что правильно — *батов*. Как же все-таки правильно?

Comment: Не вижу причин говорить "сто бат", а не "сто батов". Один бат, два бата, три бата, пять батов...

Comment: Сибиряк: _Один бат, два бата..._ === Всё таки и с граммами: один грамм, два грамма... пять граммов... Но начиная с десяти, возможна ведь и другая форма: десять грамм, пятьдесят грамм, сто грамм...

Comment: Нет, я ошибся: не с десяти. С пяти.

Comment: @slava1947 Мало ли что там с граммами. Давайте лучше в качестве примера возьмем слово "брат". Оно на "бат" намного больше похоже.Тогда будет сто батьев

Comment: Сибиряк, возьмите лучше в качестве примера "ватт".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В словаре может указываться книжная форма на ОВ, при этом существует вариант для единицы измерения с нулевым окончанием.

Сравнить: **ватт**, -а, р. мн. -ов, **счетн. ф. ватт** (ед. измер.); **грамм**, -а, р. мн. -ов, счетн. ф. **грамм и -ов** (два варианта).

**Из Интернета:**

Батов! Но, удобнее — "бат".
Эту тему уже разбирали на фарангфоруме вдоль и поперёк.
**В словаре Морева — "батов"** ! Это авторитетный источник, поверьте!

**Бат используется как единица объема**: Бат (bаt) — единица объема сыпучих веществ во Вьтнаме, равная 0,5 л. Также: Бат (ивр. ‏בת‏‎) — мера объёма жидкостей в Древнем Израиле.

Десять волов откормленных и двадцать волов с пастбища, тридцать коров пшеничной муки и шестьдесят прочей, **сто батов вина разного**, триста овец, не считая птицы откормленной, оленей, серн и сайгаков, ― все это через руки двенадцати приставников шло ежедневно к столу Соломона, а также к столу его двора, свиты и гвардии. [А. И. **Куприн. Суламифь** (1908)]

Comment: Формы "ваттов", "вольтов" и "амперов" не используются.

Comment: Не используются, вероятно, только словари дают разную информацию на этот счет, к ним и  вопрос. Общая же тенденция такова: чем более освоено слово, тем чаще выбирается форма, удобная для произношения, она может даже стать единственной, но это должно быть отражено в академических словарях.

Answer (score 1):

> Живу в Таиланде, все привыкли говорить 100 бат ...

Значит, эта норма найдёт в будущем отражение в словарях.

Когда-то и "100 грамм" были ненормативны…

Из воспоминаний К.И. Чуковского:

> Теперь мне даже странно вспомнить, как сердило меня на первых порах
>   нынешнее словосочетание: сто грамм.
>
> — Не сто грамм, а сто граммов! - с негодованием выкрикивал я.
>
> Но мало-помалу привык, обтерпелся, и теперь эта новая форма кажется
>   мне совершенно нормальной.